# laravel- how to update delivery date to table and the status for each item?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a panel page that retrieves record of the customers that are tied to the panel. I created orders table through the models and a controller as well to retrieve the records. It looks something like below:

[image]

So right now it can retrieve the data correctly but I want to allow the panel to select a date and click the submit button to update the table in the db. After submitting the date, he should not be allowed to submit any date again. Simiarly, I want to allow them to submit the order status but they can update the status as many times as they want.

**Order model:**

```
class Order extends Model
{

    // Set table
    protected $table = 'orders';

    // Set timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;

    // Set primary key
    protected $primaryKey = 'order_id';

    // Set mass assignable columns
    protected $fillable = [];

    // Manys orders can belong to one user

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Users\User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**Dashboard controller:**

```
/**
 *  Controller to handle dashboard for panel
 */
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    // Display all customer info related to panel on panel dashboard
    public function index()
    {
        $customerOrders = Order::all();

        return view('panel.panel')->with('customerOrders', $customerOrders);
    }
}
```

**Panel.blade.php:**

```
<table class="table table-light ">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Order ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Delivery Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Order Info</th>
            <th scope="col">Order Status</th>
            <th scope="col">Purchase Order</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($customerOrders as $customerOrder)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$customerOrder->order_id}}</td>
            <td><input class="date form-control" type="text" placeholder="select delivery date">
                <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Submit Date</button>
            </td>
            <td>{{$customerOrder->product_name}}</td>
            <td>
                <select id="status" name="status">
                    <option value="inProgress">In Progress</option>
                    <option value="shipped">Order Shipped</option>
                    <option value="cancelled">Cancelled</option>
                    {{-- <input type="submit" value="Submit"> --}}
                </select>
                <button>Update Status</button>
            </td>
            <td>{{$customerOrder->purchase_order}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>    
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
    }
</script>
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

In panel.blade.php, add a form around your inputs:

```
<form id="form-id" method="GET" action="/dashboard">
    {{-- Add your inputs here --}}
</form>
```

In your controller, add a $request parameter so you can access the inputs:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $inputDate = $request->inputDate;

    // Code to access your database and return results
}
```

You can also return your input date or anything else to know that your data has been filtered and then disable that field in your view.

```
return view('panel.panel')->with([
    'customerOrders' => $customerOrders,
    'inputDate' => $inputDate
]);
```

In your view you can disable the button if `$inputDate` is set:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn". {{ isset('$inputDate') ? 'disabled' : '' }}>Submit Date</button>
```

Comment: Why do you use GET but not POST?

Comment: Also, do I share the order status and delivery date input or seperate them to two diff forms?

Comment: POST would work but, in mine, I wanted to be able to copy and share the link easily e.g. www.my.site?date=yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: If you're calling two different functions, that's two different forms. If you want to process them with one function (e.g. set a number of parameters and use them for a single search button), that's one form.

Comment: I used a different way. Can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60557470/laravel-unable-to-store-values-in-soome-columns