# laravel- unable to store values in soome columns

Tags: php, laravel

I have a register controller (provided by Laravel) and I have two different registration forms (Customer and Dealer) and they both use the same controller. The difference between the two forms is that certain input fields are in one form but not the other. So my code works fine but I added three new fields (three new columns as well) to my dealer form and it's not making an insert to `occupation`, `date of birth`,`gender`, and `ethnicity` columns when I registered it.

My RegisterController.php:

```
 protected function create(array $data)
    {

        $user = User::create([
            // Users table

            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password'])
        ]);

        $user->userInfo()->create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'NRIC' => $data['nric'], // Create NRIC field.

        ]);

        $user->userAddresses()->create([
            'address_1' => $data['homeaddress1'],
            'address_2' => $data['homeaddress2'],
            'address_3' => $data['homeaddress3'],
            'zipcode' => $data['postcode'],


        ]);

        $user->userContacts()->create([

            'mobile_num' => $data['number'],
            'emergency_num' => $data['emergency']

        ]);

        // check if dealer form is registered, assign dealer role or otherwise

        if ($data['RegistrationForm'] == 2) {
            //assign track id code to dealer
            $user->track_id = 1911000000 + $user->user_id;
            $user->userInfo()->occupation = $data['occupation'];
            $user->userInfo()->ethnicity = $data['race'];
            $user->userInfo()->date_of_birth = $data['dob'];
            $user->userInfo()->gender = $data['gender'];
            $user->save();
            $user->assignRole('1');
            $user->assignRole('2');
        } else {

            //assign track id code to customer
            $user->track_id = 1913000000 + $user->user_id;

            $user->userAddresses()->shipping_address = $data['shippingaddress'];
            $user->save();
            $user->assignRole('1');
        }

        return $user;
    }
}
```

I checked my models and they seemed fine.

UserInfo model:

```
class UserInfo extends Model
{
    // Set table
    protected $table = 'user_infos';

    // Set timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;

    // Set primary key
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    // Set mass assignable columns
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'NRIC',
        'dealer_id',
        'ethnicity',
        'gender',
        'date_of_birth',
        'occupation'


    ];




    /**
     * Get the user info associated with the user.
     */

    public function user()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Users\User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

`track_id` and `assignRole` inserts fine but not those new columns I added.

Did I make any mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are not getting saved because you are not saving Userinfo properly.

Do following

```
if ($data['RegistrationForm'] == 2) {
        //assign track id code to dealer
        $user->track_id = 1911000000 + $user->user_id;
        $user->save();

        $userinfo = $user->userInfo;

        $userinfo->occupation = $data['occupation'];
        $userinfo->ethnicity = $data['race'];
        $userinfo->date_of_birth = $data['dob'];
        $userinfo->gender = $data['gender'];
        $userinfo->save();

        $user->assignRole('1');
        $user->assignRole('2');
    } else {

        //assign track id code to customer
        $user->track_id = 1913000000 + $user->user_id;

        $user->userAddresses()->shipping_address = $data['shippingaddress'];
        $user->save();
        $user->assignRole('1');
    }
```

Comment: then why does `$user->userInfo()->create` saves it?

Comment: $user->userInfo()->create() accepts fillable fields and saves it. However, you're not providing those newly added fields to the create function and instead, you're doing it while saving the user object. Remember, in your case, user and userinfo objects are two different objects.

Comment: do i need to put bracket or without like userInfo()?

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do, but in this case, my above-given code should work for you

Comment: I thought of making it better by putting the `create` into the if's statements.